# Factory pattern is the right pattern here?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a requirement where a base class method needs to be sub-classed further. There is a need to register the class object. And depending on configuration, I will decide which class to instantiate.

```
class Base {
    Base () { }
    void methodOverride() { // do something; }
}

class Derived1 extends Base {
    Derived1 () {
        super();
    }

    void methodOverride() { // specialize }
}

class Derived2 extends Base {
    Derived2 () {
        super();
    }

    void methodOverride() { // specialize }
}

class SelectorFactory {

    Base createClass( int type) {
        switch (type) {
          case DERIVED_1:
             return new Derived1();
          case DERIVED_2:
             return new Derived2();
          case BASE:
             return new Base();
        }
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    // read configuration
    int type = config.getIntType();

    SelectorFactory factory = new SelectorFactory();
    someRegisterMethod( factory.createClass(type) );
}
```

Question:
1. Do you think there is another way to implement this which would be recommended? Is this the best use of this design pattern?

Comment: A `Hashmap<Integer, Base>` is another way than what you've shown... Besides that, could you show code that compiles? `case Derived1` doesn't make sense

Comment: *Do you think there is another way to implement this?* my answer to that question is yes. But does that really help you? What is your *actual* question?

Comment: I should have mentioned - this code won't compile. I just tried to mock up the code.

Comment: I don't see why you bothered with the selectorFactory class.  In the code above it has no reason to exist.

Comment: @Matt - Sure, that was my question. What do you suggest as the right way in that case? Note: Base class already exists in a piece of code which I cannot edit. However, I have specialized it with two Derived classes to solve my specific requirements.

Comment: The factory pattern is used when you need to make the factory class itself configurable.  You are not doing that here, so it's unnecessary.  Just make a createClass(type) method that you can call directly from main().  Or just put the code in main() if you don't need to call it from anywhere else.

Comment: So, there is a default registration code which will always register the base class. In two specific cases, I will need to decide to register Derived1 or Derived2. I was hoping that this can come via configuration - as to which class I should use.

Comment: What is the added value of : `Derived2 d2=new SelectorFactory().createClass( DERIVED_2);`  over  `Derived2 d2=new Derived2();` ?

Comment: @c0der - basically, it is configuration dependent. Specific configuration decides whether to use Derived1 or Derived2. If nothing is mentioned, it remains with Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know the correct type at compile time it makes sense to have a factory.

I would use a string as an identifier instead of an integer. It makes the code easier to debug and the performance is only hurt if you use the factory in a tight loop.

Comment: I would go with an enum. You can even make the enum itself into the factory.

Comment: @shmosel: An enum would have to be changed every time the factory get support for a new implementation. And if you do not know the correct type at compile time, it doesn't really make the code more readable.

Comment: The `switch` (whether string- or int-based) would also have to changed to accommodate new factories. And the enum can be referenced by name, so you have all the flexibility and clarity of the string identifier without the bugginess.

Comment: It's just in one place, the factory method. An enum would have been useful if it had been used in multiple places in the code. For one place it just add more code to maintain.